# Use of uninitialized value $5 and argument isn't numeric in numeric lt (<)

Tags: perl, awk, sed, nagios, nagiosxi

I'm discovering the language Perl. I try to create a script to integrate inside my Nagios server, but i got two errors that I'm not able to resolve. Can you help me?

The errors are the following:

> Use of uninitialized value $5 in concatenation (.) or string at
> check_disque.pl line 53.
>
> Argument "/dev/mapper/centos-root    50G    5,5G   45G  11 /\n" isn't
> numeric in numeric lt (<) at check_disque.pl line 55.

My line 55 :

```
$espace_utilise=`df -h / | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $5}' | sed 's/%//g'`;
```

And the line 56 :

```
if ($espace_utilise < $warning) {
```

Comment: Calling Awk and `sed` from Perl is just weird; you are better off performing these filter operations natively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$espace_utilise=`df -h / | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $5}' | sed 's/%//g'`;
#                                               ^^--- here
```

The backticks interpolate variables, so `$5` will be interpolated by Perl. You can solve this by escaping the dollar sign with a backslash `\$5`, or use `qx''`, which does the same as backticks, but the single quote delimiters disables interpolation. It will cause some issues with your awk/sed commands, though. Which will require more escaping. This is one reason using shell commands inside Perl is a bad idea.

```
$espace_utilise=`df -h / | awk 'FNR == 2 {print \$5}' | sed 's/%//g'`;
$espace_utilise=qx'df -h / | awk \'FNR == 2 {print $5}\' | sed \'s/%//g\'';
```

Luckily for you, you can just do the `df` command directly and use the text processing with Perl commands, which will be a lot easier. I would help you, but I don't know exactly what that awk command does. I would guess:

```
$espace_utilise=`df -h /`;                # get the line
my $df = (split ' ', $espace_utilise)[4]; # get the 5th field
$df =~ s/%//g;                            # remove %. Can also use tr/%d//d
```

The other error:

> Argument "/dev/mapper/centos-root 50G 5,5G 45G 11 /\n" isn't numeric in numeric lt (<) at check_disque.pl line 55. My line 55 :

...is just because the first statement failed. Perl interpolates `$5` even though it warns about it, and it becomes the empty string instead. So your awk line just says `{ print  }`, which I assume is the same as printing the whole line. So if you fix the first part, you can ignore this.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm discovering the language PERL.

Then take a look at [CPAN](https://www.perl.org/cpan.html). Among many modules there is [`Filesys::DiskSpace`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filesys::DiskSpace) which does what you want. You need to install it first. In order to do that you need to learn how to [INSTALL](https://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html) modules from CPAN, following

```
cpan App::cpanminus
cpanm Filesys::DiskSpace
```

should work in your case. Note that if you did not use `cpan` earlier it might ask you if you want it to autoconfigure itself. Hit enter to say yes.

After installation usage is as simple as

```
use Filesys::DiskSpace;
($fs_type, $fs_desc, $used, $avail, $fused, $favail) = df $dir;
```

Note that it does not provide percentage implicitly, so you would need to follow [`df`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/df.1posix.html) behavior

```
      The percentage of the normally available space that is currently allocated  to  all
      files on the file system. This shall be calculated using the fraction:

      <space used>/( <space used>+ <space free>)

   expressed as a percentage. This percentage may be greater than 100 if <space free> is less
   than zero. The percentage value shall  be  expressed  as  a  positive  integer,  with  any
   fractional result causing it to be rounded to the next highest integer.
```